# Is it possible to alter the auto generated event handler code within visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I would like to be able to control the default code that's generated for event's when I use one of Visual Studio's automatically generated blocks. The current template is as follows:

```
void HandlerName(object sender, HandlerEventArgs e) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I would like to change this to the following:

```
private void HandlerName(object sender, HandlerEventArgs args) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Namely it's the `args` argument that I always change.

**UPDATE**: Further to this it is policy that we also include comments for private members here, thus another use-case for my requirement is to also generate the default comment.

**UPDATE 2**: I now retract the reasoning for wanting to rename `e` to `args` due to evidence of a non-standard naming convention, however I still would like to override the template if possible for explicit access modifier and default comments.

Comment: frankly, I'd like it to automatically put the `private` on.

Comment: Agreed, though it's not as important to me as private is the default access modifier for members. I particularly would like `args` instead of `e` due to the face I tend to use `e` within lambda expressions a lot, especially lambda events where `(s, e)` is desired, though I've recently changed to `(s, a)`.

Comment: There's a reason that the event arguments parameter is always named `e`. It's a standard convention in the .NET world, recommended by all official and unofficial style guides, and I highly advise that you begin following it. Modifying it to `args` is quite non-standard, which hurts readability for absolutely no benefit.

Comment: Not to get into a debate, though I don't think it's less readable or confusing. Personally I think that `e` only became a standard by proxy from VS's auto-generation. It is interesting that `sender` is not by default `s` which is where I personally see the inconsistency, and not all `EventArgs` start with `e`, but all end in `Args`.

Comment: @Brett - it didn't "become" a standard through VS's auto generation. It was always in the [design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0eyck3s(v=vs.71).aspx) that the two arguments be called *sender* and *e*.

Comment: @Damien, Thanks for the clarification, I now retract my reasoning to rename `e` to `args`, though I would still like to override the template for comments and explicit access modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `e` comes from the delegate signature (`delegate void HandlerEventHandler(object sender, HandlerEventArgs e)`), so you can't change it without also changing the delegate signature...

Comment: Very understandable reasoning Thomas, +1 for that. I'd still be very interested in a way to get VS to format this automatically, even leaving the name of `e`. I know that what I'm asking only takes a few seconds to manually override, however it's still a few seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to change the auto-generated code when you create an event handler?

My answer is no, but I am not really sure why you would need to.

Comment: My reasoning is illustrated within the example provided, though I do wish to extend this further by also providing the default comments for the handler. It is policy for us here to also comment private members.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you still want to change something to the auto-generated code for event handler, I use [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/14f62cb9-b559-4bad-9388-37da2150e238) extension for Visual Studio since a couple of years.

It's very helpful to generate more clean event handler name. As you will see, instead of generating something like txtName_LostFocus, the extension will suggest to you a method with name like this: OnNameLostFocus.

This help getting rid of underscore and prefixes that we usually add to controls. The extension have a configuration screen to add all the prefixes that you want.

But everything I say is not helpful for answering your question. Here is where it help -> In the code that you can download, you can see how the engine works to replace the name of the event handler method and I'm totally sure that you can found a solution to rename any argument you want (if you still want) and also, add an explicit modifier.

I will try to find the solution and let you know of my progress.

**UPDATE:**
You can also use Resharper who will automatically if you want add explicit modifier for you using the clean up engine.